# How to change text in the call alert view when making a phone call?

Tags: ios, swift

Right now I'm using this to make a call:

```
private func executeCall(phone:String){

    if let url = URL(string: "tel://" + phone), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        if #available(iOS 10, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }
}
```

It works but I want to change the text:"cancel" and "call" to a different language.  How can we do that?

Comment: The language is dependent on the language being used by the device's owner. There isn't any way to do so for security reasons.

Comment: localized strings will be used to change the text based on the language the user chooses in their device.